# Nesting WPF 3.5 sp1 toolkit datagrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, nested, toolkit

Has anybody been successful or can find an example of using nested grids in the WPF 3.5 SP1 toolkit Datagrid? Does anybody know if this is even supported? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can nest a datagrid inside another datagrid's rowtemplate.  Remember in WPF you can put any control inside any container.

Comment: I belive it's called the RowDetailsTemplate or something.

Comment: Haha thanks guys. That totally worked. In case anybody else is looking for a good place to start:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDataGridExamples.aspx