# Extensive tutorial on list view in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, listview

In the near future, we will have to develop some advanced interface which I believe will be possible with list views . Basically, it will consist of multiple columns (number is determined at page load and can be refresh at demand) and multiple line. Each 'cell' will be defined in the future but will not be too complicated, a few text boxes but nothing dynamic in this part.

My problem is coming from the header, which will consists of two layers and the big one will therefore contain many small ones. Since it will contains a lot of date, I will also need to scroll horizontally and vertically.

I'm pretty sure all of this is possible some way or another and maybe with list views, so I was wondering if anyone ever did this. Also, while I'm exploring ListViews, I was looking for a really good extensive tutorial on those.

Comment: Also, it sounds like you are really using the ListView as a datagrid.  If so, have you looked at the <DataGrid>?  Somewhat different plumbing on them.  See the DataGrid vs ListView (GridView) in my post below.

Comment: I understand that I use the datagrids vocabulary, but I really mean a listview. I'm pretty sure listview got headers and the concept of column, but never used it. I don't think Datagrid would let me enough freedom to do what I need.

Comment: Well ListView has a GridView, and that I have worked with some.  It has columns, rows, sorting and whatnot, but I abandoned it in favor of the DataGrid as it seemed to be a lot easier to work with in the end.  Granted my work with GridView was like a year and a half ago and right when I started learning about WPF...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted the below while in the midst of experiencing a small aneurism in my brain.  It does not precisely apply to this post as ListVIEWs are not discussed very much in the mentioned articles.

I have found [**this series of articles**](http://drwpf.com/blog/itemscontrol-a-to-z/) written by Dr. WPF to be extremely helpful when using ItemsControls.

[**'L' is for Lookless**](http://drwpf.com/blog/2009/05/12/itemscontrol-l-is-for-lookless/) is of particular interest as it describes how styles, and templates can be used effectively for an easilly changable display of your items.

There is also a DataGrid control which may work better for you depending on what you want to do with it:

[**DataGrid vs ListView(GridView)**](http://wpf.codeplex.com/discussions/40802?ProjectName=wpf)

Here is a pretty good [**tutorial for the GridView**](http://www.wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html).

And an [**SO article**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030047/nesting-wpf-3-5-sp1-toolkit-datagrid) for nesting datagrids.

Comment: I didn't find exactly what I was looking for, but I did find an alternate way of doing the same thing, so in the end it worked out well.